# Template's main menu not responsive -how to fix it?

Tags: templates, menu, responsive-web-design

I am using a free joomla template called [qualify](http://jomboom.com/template/1012/Qualify/)  which says is fully responsive in ios and android, but I tested it today on my samsung phone and there is no main menu showing.

Where could I change code to make the menu show?
Here is [site](http://notabadartist.com) I'm working on. I know the lines of code in styles.css pertaining to the menu but still don't know why it is not showing on mobile device.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the min-width 829pix part in the CSS? I think that's where you need to start looking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The menu **is** there but due to the colour of the dropdown trigger, it's very hard to see as it's blending in with the background. The image below shows you:

[image]

You can change the colour on line **80** of **styles.css** in your template:

```
nav a#pull {
    background-color: #283744; /* CHANGE ME */
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I'm not going to lie, the template is extremely bad. It has not been developed very well. This is not your fault but I would strongly suggest looking at an alternative.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I must study about creating templates. This is brilliant though, much appreciated.